# Flutter - Image repeat only scales to screen size, not parent size

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that allows the user to drag a scale to select a value, similar to the basic Slider widget but "inverted" i.e. the value sliders position is fixed and you move the scale in the background to adjust the value.
The scale should be unbounded / infinite and I thought I could use a small image + `ImageRepeat.repeatX` for that. But it seems this only scales to the initially visible screen, not to the actual parent width.

Is there a way to force it to fill the entire parents width or update after a `translate`?

Minimal example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderTest extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _SliderTestState createState() => _SliderTestState();
}

class _SliderTestState extends State<SliderTest> {
double foo = 100.0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('SliderTest'),
  ),
  body: new Builder(builder: (context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("$foo"),
          new GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragUpdate: (v) { setState(() { foo += v.primaryDelta; }); },
            child: new Container(
              width: 5000.0,
              height: 80.0,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: new Transform.translate(
                offset: new Offset(foo, 0.0),
                child: new Image.network('http://4d94o75ofvdkz8tr3396n8cn.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/Scale_4x.jpg', repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX,)
              )
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  })
);
}
}
```

The parent `Container` is clearly wide enough as seen by the green background color, but the transformed image only scales to the initial screen width and not beyond.
Is there a way to fix that without using a huge image file?

Answer (score 3):

That is actually wrong. `repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX` do fill the parent, not the screen.

The problem is that even although you defined your parent with a with of `5000.0`, it doesn't actually have that width. As `Column` adds a maximum width constraint to its children.

What you need is to add an in-between widget that *can be bigger on the inside*.
This can be an `OverflowBox` or a `SingleChildScrolLView`, even a `ConstrainedBox`.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for pointing that out! I'd have expected flutter to give some sort of warning if a given width is being ignored I guess?! First attempt with `OverflowBox` resulted in an infinite overflow at bottom exception, I'll try again tomorrow when I have more time. Thanks for the tip, much appreciated!

Comment: Many UI widgets (buttons, listtile, ...) contain such warning. But `Container` is too low level. Although you can manually add this warning using `SafeArea`

Comment: Can you let me know where you'd put the `OverflowBox` in the widget tree Rémi? I can't seem to make it work without getting the infinite overflow exception.

Comment: Right above container.

Comment: Unfortunately I always get: `flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderConstrainedOverflowBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler object was given an infinite size during layout.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Rect argument contained a NaN value.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.`